# how to get raw data after a query in mysql?

Tags: c++, mysql

After a query from mysql, How could I get the raw data in memory?
I hope to get the pointer to data in csv-like format.

```
char tmp[256];
sprintf(tmp,"select * from my_data");                                       
mysql_query(&DbObj,tmp); 

char * pointer = RESULT; //How to GET this RESULT, is there a short-cut?
```

If I print the pointer, I hope to get something like:

```
peter 1234
sue 2332
...
```

I searched at the mysql.h for it, and I can't find it.
I think it is at some corner.

Comment: I'll put good odds that it doesn't exist. SQL results are normally returned via "cursor", which normally gives you access to only one row at a time, so to get the whole result as a single string, you'd have to walk through the rows and concatenate them together.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to execute your queries like this

```
mysql -u username -p -D database -N -B -e "select * from my_data"
```

where

- `-p` alone asks for the user password or you can type `-pPASSWORD`(there is no space after p)
- `-N` or `--skip-column-names` excludes the column headers
- `-B` or `--batch` prints results using tab as the column separator
- `-e` is your SQL query

You can find more [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/mysql-run-query-bash-script-linux-command-line/)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns the data by copying (assigning) from the database into your variable.  For larger fields, such as BLOBs, the data is transfered by using a stream.

MySQL will execute your query and return a dataset or table.  You will need to load the items from the record, then execute the *Next* function to advance to the next row.

If you want to transfer the entire result set (table) into *memory* you may want to review the driver source code.  I am not certain if MySQL is set up to transfer whole tables into memory.

Is there a need for you to access the table directly rather than using the MySQL API?